# Reg Ex shows invalid Escape sequence

Tags: java, regex

The following Reg Ex :-

```
^((((\(\d{3}\))|(\d{3}-))\d{3}-\d{4})|(\+?\d{2}((-| )\d{1,8}){1,5}))(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$
```

when tried to be implemented shows

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

Can anyone help me sort out the issue?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to parse with this regex?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to try and parse this monstrous regex, but the error points to a problem with string escaping. You need to double all the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
^((((\\(\\d{3}\\))|(\\d{3}-))\\d{3}-\\d{4})|(\\+?\\d{2}((-| )\\d{1,8}){1,5}))(( x| ext)\\d{1,5}){0,1}$
```

In Java strings the `\` backslash character starts an escape sequence for a 'special' character. Like `\n` for newline.

You can escape your strings with tools [like this one here](http://www.htmlescape.net/javaescape_tool.html) if you don't want to do it by hand.